# Azure: Angular Pipeline Allways fails on Build with SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: angular, azure, command-line-interface

Hey guys recentely i added a repo to my angular app on azure dev opps. I created a pipeline to run and build. When it reaches the build phase it allways fails. im stuck in this for a while.
[Agent jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98SdU.png)

[Angular CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0PBf.png)

[Where it fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EV80.png)

if i run locally it allways work fines but on azure it allways fails.. i don't know what to do

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Sass compiler to be able to find the MDC Web Sass files. In your `angular.json`, make sure `node_modules/` is listed as a Sass include path:

```
...
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss"
],      
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "node_modules/"
  ]
},
...
```

Check out [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/trimox/angular-mdc-web/issues/2120) around the same.